# Disable anchor link in table based on the values in the first column

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to know how I can disable my last anchor column. If the values in the first row are NOT 1 or 7
I can do this with input tags, but I can't figure out how to emulate this with anchor tags in my last row.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <style>
             table,
             th,
             td {
             border: 1px solid black;
             border-collapse: collapse;
             }
             th,
             td {
             padding: 15px;
             text-align: left;
             }
             #t01 {
             width: 100%;
             background-color: #fff;
             }
          </style>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
         
          <table class="table table-striped">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th>column1</th>
                   <th>column2</th>
                   <th>column3</th>
                   <th>column4</th>
                   <th>column5</th>
                   <th>column6</th>
                   <th>column7</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                <tr>
                   <td>5</td>
                   <td>
                      test-1
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-2
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-3
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-4
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-5
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="/Doctor/">Doctor</a>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>7</td>
                   <td>
                      test-1
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-2
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-3
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-4
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-5
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="/Park/">Park</a>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>
                      test-1
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-2
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-3
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-4
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-5
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="/Office/">Office</a>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>
                      test-1
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-2
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-3
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-4
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-5
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="/Home/">Home</a>
                   </td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                   <td>6</td>
                   <td>
                      test-1
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-2
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-3
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-4
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      test-5
                   </td>
                   <td>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnSubmit" value="submit">
                   </td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
          </table>
          <script>
             // creating an Array of the values that should cause the <input>
             // to be disabled:
             const disableValues = [1, 7];
             
             // here we find all the <input> elements in the td:last-child element
             // within the <tbody>:
             $('tbody td:last-child input')
             
               // and use the prop() method to update the value of the
               // 'disabled' property:
               .prop('disabled', function() {
             
                 // here we navigate from the current <input> to the closest
                 // ancestor <tr> element and from there find the td:first-child
                 // element and retrieve its text:
                 let firstColValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text();
             
                 // here we return whether Boolean true (if the numeric value of the
                 // text in the first <td> is included in the array of values) or
                 // false (if that value is not in the array of values):
                 
                 return !disableValues.includes(+firstColValue);
             });
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: How would you do it for input tags? What's different? I'm not really clear on your question. It would benefit from taking a few minutes to clarify it.

Comment: You're selecting an input where you should be select an anchor `<a>` and anchors don't have a disabled property

Comment: @Slbox so I added a input button in the table for an example. I want to emulate the same disable behavior for anchor tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "disable" the anchor tags, but if you want to prevent them from navigating the user when clicked on, perhaps you could try this:

```js
$("tr").each(function () {
  const $children = $(this).children();
  const firstColVal = parseInt($children[0].innerText, 10);

  if ([1, 7].includes(firstColVal)) {
    $($children[$children.length - 1]).find('a').removeAttr('href').addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td><a href="//google.com">Google</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td><a href="//google.com">Google</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td><a href="//google.com">Google</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$($children[$children.length - 1]).find('a').removeAttr('href');
 $($children[$children.length - 1]).find('a').addClass( "disabled" );` I added this to it. which made it have a disabled effect. Thank you everyone

Comment: @taji01 Updated my answer to include the CSS class you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead use toggleClass to toggle a class called disabled. Then create an event listener for disabled anchors, and simply do a preventdefault on the event to stop anything from happening when you click on it. After that, play with the CSS class of disabled to get your desired look.

```
$('tbody td:last-child a')
               .toggleClass('disabled', function() {
                 let firstColValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text();
                 return !disableValues.includes(+firstColValue);
             });

$(document).on("click","a.disabled",function(e){e.preventDefault();});


.disabled{color:silver;opacity:0.5;pointer-events:none}
```

Comment: Maybe add `pointer-events:none` though focus would still work

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody > tr').forEach(tr => {
//for each tr

  var num = tr.querySelector('td:first-of-type').innerText;
//get first column text (number)

  if ((num !== "7") === false || (num !== "1") === false) {
// if not 1 or 7

  tr.querySelector('td:last-of-type ').innerHTML = num;
    }
// on last td replace inner HTML with a link text
});
```

or just set `.style.pointerEvents = "none";` that will disable `a href` link, but button stays, not a good UX, but do as you wish.

```js
// creating an Array of the values that should cause the <input>
// to be disabled:
const disableValues = [1, 7];

// here we find all the <input> elements in the td:last-child element
// within the <tbody>:
$('tbody td:last-child input')

  // and use the prop() method to update the value of the
  // 'disabled' property:
  .prop('disabled', function() {

    // here we navigate from the current <input> to the closest
    // ancestor <tr> element and from there find the td:first-child
    // element and retrieve its text:
    let firstColValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text();

    // here we return whether Boolean true (if the numeric value of the
    // text in the first <td> is included in the array of values) or
    // false (if that value is not in the array of values):

    return !disableValues.includes(+firstColValue);
  });


document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody > tr').forEach(tr => {
  var num = tr.querySelector('td:first-of-type').innerText;
  if ((num !== "7") === false || (num !== "1") === false) {
    tr.querySelector('td:last-of-type ').innerHTML = num;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    #t01 {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>column1</th>
        <th>column2</th>
        <th>column3</th>
        <th>column4</th>
        <th>column5</th>
        <th>column6</th>
        <th>column7</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>
          test-1
        </td>
        <td>
          test-2
        </td>
        <td>
          test-3
        </td>
        <td>
          test-4
        </td>
        <td>
          test-5
        </td>
        <td>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="/Doctor/">Doctor</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>
          test-1
        </td>
        <td>
          test-2
        </td>
        <td>
          test-3
        </td>
        <td>
          test-4
        </td>
        <td>
          test-5
        </td>
        <td>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="/Park/">Park</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          test-1
        </td>
        <td>
          test-2
        </td>
        <td>
          test-3
        </td>
        <td>
          test-4
        </td>
        <td>
          test-5
        </td>
        <td>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="/Office/">Office</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          test-1
        </td>
        <td>
          test-2
        </td>
        <td>
          test-3
        </td>
        <td>
          test-4
        </td>
        <td>
          test-5
        </td>
        <td>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="/Home/">Home</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mousedown` to preempt the normal click behavior and call `event.preventDefault()` from the `mousedown` handler.